# HTML Table design

Tags: html, html-table

I need to display my table in this desired format.

[image: Design]

I am not sure as to how to achieve a column within a column (AA, MQ) under a super column (Aug-18)).

Answer (score 2):

You need to think about it the other way around.

The month headings are headings for two columns, they aren't a single column with multiple columns inside them.

Make the headings span multiple columns with [the `colspan` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan).

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid #aaa 1px;
  padding: 1ex;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <th scope=col colspan=2> Aug-18
            <th scope=col colspan=2> Sep-18
        <tr>
            <td>
            <th scope=col> AA <!-- These should probably have <abbr> elements -->
            <th scope=col> MQ
            <th scope=col> AA 
            <th scope=col> MQ
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope=row> Count1
            <td> 0
            <td> 0
            <td> 0
            <td> 0
        <tr>
            <th scope=row> Count2
            <td> 0
            <td> 0
            <td> 0
            <td> 0
        <tr>
            <th scope=row> Count3
            <td> 0
            <td> 0
            <td> 0
            <td> 0
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th scope=row> Total
            <td> 0
            <td> 0
            <td> 0
            <td> 0
</table>
```

Comment: Thank You. I assume I would have the flexibility to pass derived values from backend instead of <td> 0.
I am not able to achieve the border for the table as you did even though I have defined the same in my css.

Comment: Your backend can generate whatever data you want in the table. I've no idea why you have been unable to apply the CSS.

Comment: It was a deployment connection error. Resolved after that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Quentin, any idea how to make these 
-><th scope=col colspan=2> Aug-18
   <th scope=col colspan=2> Sep-18
-><th scope=col> AA 
   <th scope=col> MQ
-><th scope=row> Count1
    <td> 0
    <td> 0
    <td> 0
DYNAMIC based on the result we retrieve from backend?
I might need only Aug-18 or might need more than Aug-18,Sep-18. Same with the other attributes too

Comment: @SaiC.M.Naidu — I have no idea how to convert the raw data (in a format you haven't shown us) to this HTML using your choice of programming language (which you haven't shared), template language (ditto), etc (ditto again). You could ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

```css
.this-tbl { width: 100%; }
th, td {
border: 1px solid #333;
padding: 4px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" class="this-tbl">
    <tr>
 <th></th>
 <th colspan="2">Aug-18</th>
 <th colspan="2">Sep-18</th>
 <th colspan="2">Oct-18</th>
 <th colspan="2">Nov-18</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
 <td></td>
 <td>AA</td>
 <td>MQ</td>
 <td>AA</td>
 <td>MQ</td>
 <td>AA</td>
 <td>MQ</td>
 <td>AA</td>
 <td>MQ</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
 <td>Count1</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
 <td>Count2</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
 <td>Count3</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
 <td>Total</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```